# The division in the z3 java API

Tags: java, z3, division

I just found the division in Z3 JAVA API named "mkDiv()" refers to the integer division but not the normal one. For example:

```
ArithExpr a = ctx.mkDiv(ctx.mkInt(3),ctx.mkInt(5)).simplify();
```

the result of a is "0" but "3/5".

In the [tutor](https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h24), the division and integer division seem to be 2 part separately:
(assert (= r1 (div a 4))) ; integer division
(assert (>= b (/ c 3.0)))
where is the division in the Z3 java api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mkDiv` will do the right thing based on its arguments. Since you are passing integers, it'll do integer division. To use real division, you need to pass real values as arguments:

```java
import com.microsoft.z3.*;
  
class A {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      Context ctx = new Context();
      ArithExpr a = ctx.mkDiv(ctx.mkReal(3),ctx.mkReal(5));
      System.out.println(a.simplify());
   };
};
```

This prints:

```
3/5
```